# I'm writing a function to find the list of prime numbers from 2 to a number 'n'

Tags: r

I know there are multiple ways to do this but right now I want to figure out why my code below does not work. I'm writing the code below and expecting to get a list of prime numbers from 2 to the number 'n'. Instead it only returns the number "2". For example, if I run prime.list(10), it returns 2 instead of returning 2,3,5 and 7

`prime.list <- function(n) {
  for (i in 2:n) {
    if (i==2) { 
      return(i)
      }
  else if (sum(i %% 2:(i-1)==0) == 0){
    return(i)
  }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You're only returning one value in your function. The for loop starts with i=2, enters the if statement, and then the function terminates since you return 2.

Comment: Yes thanks! - it works fine if I replace 'return' with 'print'